# Mac OS X Lion - forward all connections on port 22 to external ip

Tags: port-forwarding, transparent-proxy, osx-lion

I need to forward all connection to any address port 22 to a different gateway (i.e. no default).
Firstly I suppose to do it with ipfw:

```
sudo ipfw add 5 fwd $EXTERNAL_IP,22 tcp from any to any 22 keep-state
```

But with Mac OS X Lion it seems do not work.
Anyway, looking at ipfw documentation I see it is deprecated and I should use pfctl.

So I have modified `/etc/pf.conf` file:

```
rdr proto tcp from $internal_ip to any port 22 -> $external_ip port 22
```

But with no luck.

Does anyone know how to translate or forward all connections generated by local applications to any address but port 22 to a different gateway/ip address?

**Update**

Following Jake's suggestion I tried to specify only destination IP, so I converted rdr rule to mac os x syntax:

```
rdr proto tcp from any to any port 22 -> $external_ip port 22
```

Even in this case I didn't get results I expected, i.e. I can connect via ssh to my server but through default gateway.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm trying myself to insert a transparent proxy on localhost between localhost and external services and with no luck. My guess is that OS X just joined Windows on this front - no more NAT support at system firewall level, but I still hope it can be done.

Comment: No, I have abandoned and switched on linux.

Comment: exactly what i did, in fact; thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

```
rdr pass on $internal_ip inet proto tcp from any to any port 22
```

Not an expert by any means, think that should do it. Been a *long* time since I used anything other than iptables :)

Comment: Thanks Jake for your tentative to help, unfortunately this syntax is not supported and even trying to correct the rdr rule didn't give the expected result. I have updated my question with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find a port of **rinetd** for Mac OS X.